# Access 2010-To input or auto generate?

Tags: database, database-design

In Access 2010, I am trying to set up an ID number field (It is not the primary key) where it inputs the numbers from a barcode. In the same field, if the barcode is not available, I want an option to auto generate a number in that space. The user could press a button to autogenerate the number.

In other words for each record, I want to be an ID number that is either scanned from a bar code or auto generate by pressin a button.

Can I do this in MS Access or is it too much?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> In other words for each record, I want to be an ID number that is
>   either scanned from a bar code or auto generate by pressin [sic] a button.

Access (any version) can do that.

But you want either an ID number that's scanned from a bar code, or an ID number that's *generated by VBA code* called from the [Click event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822439%28v=office.14%29.aspx) of a button.

You'll need to write the VBA code.  Guarantee collisions can't occur between ID numbers read from a bar code and ID numbers generated by your code. One way, assuming all the bar code ID numbers are positive, is to have your code generate only negative ID numbers. There are other ways.